# What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

Tags: discussion, 7-questions, on-topic

From the [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/):

---

### What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger. You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes *what your site is about*. Every word counts!

This is what our [help page defining on-topic questions](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says currently:

> Sustainable Living Stack Exchange is for folks dedicated to a lifestyle that can be maintained indefinitely without depleting available resources.

Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:

- the tagline
- the motto
- the blurb under the logo
- a convenience redirect “nickname” for the site
- perhaps eventually the domain name in some form

(Due to a variety of [practical difficulties with domain names](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/), we prefer to de-emphasize domain name selection. Most sites will retain their `topic.stackexchange.com` names indefinitely.)

Naming is hard — *really* hard. But if you can come up with a sensible elevator pitch for your community, it’s a great starting point.

For more detail see: [Stack Exchange Naming for Dummies](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/)

Comment: I must admit that I'm a bit surprised this hasn't received more attention from the community. Your "elevator pitch" should reflect your identity as a site. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sustainable living is balancing of accounts between costs we impose on our environment and the benefit that we derive from modern goods and services.

Adapted from the Wackernagel school of environmental accounting.

Answer (score 1):

Sustainable Living is about how one can lead a lifestyle that can be maintained indefinitely. In other words, it's about reuse, reduce and recycle and about how we can use the Earth's resources wisely.

Just to get people started I've also added my suggestion for a tagline and motto to this post, but I think we should create separate posts for these once we have decided on a good elevator pitch. So a vote for this post is a vote for the text above.

- **Tagline**: Sustainable Living: all the answers for the future.
- **Motto**: *Waste nothing*

  or *It's eco-logical*

  or  the plain old *Reuse, reduce and recycle*

Comment: Could you put each of those as a separate answer? That way, each can be voted on independently

Comment: @EnergyNumbers perhaps we should focus mainly on the elevator pitch for now and create separate meta-questions for the tagline and motto.